# Fetch All in APSW

Tags: python, database, sqlite, apsw

You know there isn't any "fetchall" method for APSW. We can only use `.next()` method. So How can I take the result of an execute command with select query into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3.6.22 of apsw let me use `cursor.fetchall()` to retrieve all rows in a list:

```
import apsw

conn = apsw.Connection(':memory:')
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(255))")
curs.executemany("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?, ?)", [(1, 'bar'),(2, 'baz')])
print curs.execute("SELECT * FROM foo").fetchall()

[(1, u'bar'), (2, u'baz')]
```

If your version does not support this, but it supports `.next()`, can you just wrap the cursor in a list (iterating over the cursor)?  This works for me:

```
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM foo")
print list(curs)

[(1, u'bar'), (2, u'baz')]
```

Comment: (Disclosure: I am the APSW author)

APSW 3.6.6.2 released in December 2008 added cursor.fetchall().  It is actually more characters to type than wrapping the cursor in list()!